# Query wordpress posts on static page

Tags: posts, loop

I'm working with Wordpress theme where i need to show my posts in a static page.There is a only one section in site where we need to add posts frequently (services) and i need to fetch these posts on services page .

I did not know how to workout with loop in a static page , if someone could help with it that would be great help

Answer (score 0):

By static page do you mean a WP page or do you mean a HTML page within the site?

If it's the first you need a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/), if it's the latter then you need to include wp-blog-header.php into the file with php.

Comment: i mean a warderess page like we do have in nav home . about us   ....

Comment: Yep so you need the page template, add to your theme folder and add the page template header to the file and it will show in the templates dropdown for pages.

Comment: reference to any tutorial please i'm new to Wordpress .

Comment: I linked to one in my answer - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Comment: thank you very much sir ,first query in wordpress forum  and got the answer  Love it ..!